# Is there a Germanic word for the Latin "number"?

Tags: etymology, germanic-languages

Really just a curiosity, but I've been unable to find such a thing on my own...

I figure something as simple as *a word for the thing you count with* should exist in any language which has terms for counting. It's definitely possible we had no such thing ourselves, and had to borrow the term.

My knowledge of other Germanic languages (Icelandic, Faroese, and Dutch mostly) only includes cognates of "number". If we were using a Germanic word before, does anyone know what it was?

Comment: Do you mean something like _Zahl_ or _Ziffer_ ?

Comment: What did a thesaurus give for synonyms of 'number'?

Comment: @mplongjan: The cognate of *Ziffer* is *cipher*, but its origin is not Germanic, it's ultimately [Arabic](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=cipher&allowed_in_frame=0).

Comment: It's worth considering that, in simple terms, prior to their invention by the Arabs, and our adoption of them during the Enlightenment, Westerners never had *numbers*. We could count, but counting only gives you an *amount*, and from amounts rise fractions, but until you have conceptual distinction between nothing and zero, you do not have the *concept* of numbers, only amounts, which can be expressed with *numerals*. On that basis, I assume there will be no original Germanic word for numbers in the modern sense.

Comment: @Carl Smith: I have no idea what the conceptual distinction between nothing and zero would be, and I'm a mathematical logician. I very much doubt that this is required to develop a word for number in the sense of the question that was asked here. I think it's a pretty safe bet that anyone who spoke a language that could reasonably be called Germanic already had methods for recording numbers, though there may have been many for the different things typically being counted. This makes a word for numbers almost a necessity.

Comment: The conceptual difference lies in nothing being the lowest amount you can have; no amount can be less than nothing. Zero is just a number, like `-1` is just a number, on an infinite line. If you replace the absence of something (a `null` value) with `0`, you'll mess up even basic arithmetic, like finding a mean. The OP makes it clear that they believe "something as simple as a word for the thing you count with should exist in any language with counting", which is overly simplistic. A word meaning *amount* should exist, but a word meaning *number* would not.

Comment: @CarlSmith I fully understand the semantic difference between null (often used for an unitialized value) and 0; I've been programming for about 12 years now, and that part is extremely clear to me. What I'm not clear about, is how “amount" (literally to “go up”) means only the initialized values, while “number” means all values initialized or otherwise.

Comment: @HansAdler As I understand it: 1 > 0 resolves to true, as you are familiar with. 1 > null cannot resolve to any Boolean value though. Depending on the logic you're working with, this is often something like “unknown” or “undecided”.

Comment: @PatrickKelly - It's not really to do with initialisation, though I get what you're saying there. It's just that a number, as an abstract concept, is something very different to an amount. We agree on that, but I'm suggesting [only suggesting] that while people may have named some of the common amounts [the low and round numbers], like a *dozen*, a *score* or a *hundred*, they'd still lack the concept of numbers proper, so they wouldn't have a word for that idea. I'd expect 'amount names', including common fractions, and words like *tally*, but not a word that describes integers, reals etc.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not super committed to defending this line of reasoning. It just seemed like it'd make an interesting comment. I still think there's some truth to what I said, but I haven't given it enough thought to be sure, and certainly not enough to argue the point.

Comment: @CarlSmith it's certainly an important consideration; one I hadn't made. I appreciate it.

Comment: Following on Carl's line of thinking, it is probable that you could not separate the count from the thing being counted until the Arabic system came into use. There might have been a word or symbol for five cows, and a different one for five geese, but the idea of five did not have a symbol. Prior to the Arabic system, tax records show not only different symbols for five of different things, they often counted different things in different bases and mixed radix systems!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the word that English used before borrowing *number* from Latin/French was probably *tale*. I couldn't confirm this directly with etymological online sources, but there is a lot of circumstantial evidence.

German *Zahl*, Dutch *getal* and Danish *tal* together with German/Dutch/Danish *Anzahl/aantaal/antal* and *Nummer/nummer/nummer* cover most or perhaps all uses of English *number*. *Zahl/getal/tal* is the most basic meaning; the other words can and must be used for certain special uses:

> The *number* of *number*s under 6 is five. *Number* 5.
>
> Die An*zahl* *Zahl*en unter 6 ist fünf. *Nummer* 5.
>
> Het aan*tal* ge*tal*len minder dan 6 is vijf. *Nummer* 5.
>
> An*tall*et af *tal* under 6 er fem. *Nummer* 5.

The telling of a story is related to counting in that you say one event, or number, after another, in the correct order. That's why you can "recount" a story (or give an "account" of it), and that's why the words for counting and telling a story are related in the Germanic languages other than English.

> I am *count*ing my sheep. I am *tell*ing a story.
>
> Ich *zähl*e meine Schafe. Ich er*zähl*e eine Geschichte.
>
> Ik *tel* mijn schapen. Ik ver*tel* een verhaal.
>
> Jeg *tæller* mine får. Jeg for*tæll*er en historie.

In English, the counting sense of *tell* has mostly been superseded by the story-telling sense and replaced by Latin words, but traces of it survive e.g. in *tally* as a synonym for *reckoning* or *account* and in *teller* as a word for someone for whom counting money (rather than telling stories) is part of the job description.

The etymonline articles on [tell](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=tell) and [tale](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=tale) are relevant. In particular, etymonline says this about *tale*:

> The secondary Modern English sense of "number, numerical reckoning" (c. 1200) probably was the primary one in Germanic [...].

(I was a bit puzzled by what appears to be an implicit claim that *tale* has a numerical secondary sense in Modern English. But TimLymington cleared this up with a comment quoting Chambers with the archaic phrase "a tale of years".)

I don't know if this answers your question in the title with a *yes* or *no* because it's not entirely clear whether you are looking for a word in Proto-Germanic (which apparently would be *talo*) or for a modern English word of Germanic origin. The latter doesn't seem to exist because the number sense of the word *tale* itself was lost completely in English, in favour of *number*, unlike the other Germanic languages that evolved a differentiation of meaning between the cognates of *tale* and the cognates of *number* that essentially puts the former into a mathematical context and the latter into a numerical naming context.

Comment: *Tale* itself can mean 'number or reckoning (*archaic*)'  according to Chambers, for example. 'Your tale of years' is your age, not your life history.

Comment: @TimLymington: Thanks, I wasn't familiar with that phrase.

Comment: _Taal_ is Dutch for _language_. There are the common _aantal_ (number: het aantal appels -> the number of appels) and the slightly archaic _tal_ (in fixed expressions: _tal van mensen_ -> a lot of people). Then there is _getal_, number as in "zes is een **getal** -> six is a number.

Comment: @oerkens: Thanks for alerting me to this stupid mistake. I hope it's correct now after my latest edit. Thanks also for reminding me of the *aantal* sense, which I am also going to add now.

Comment: *Tale* here describes a *tally*, which is only a number if you conceptualise it as being one. Prior to mathematics, a tally would be an *amount*, not a *number*. See my comment on the question.

Comment: Given that English, and many Germanic languages, use a decent amount of analytical semantics, does it seem reasonable to consider a word like "tale" as a sequence or ordering of anything, and when used in context, the semantics are resolved to be the same as the Latin "number"?

Comment: @Patrick Kelly: Yes, I think this sounds reasonable, though prefixes as in the modern Germanic languages probably also played an important role. I would imagine something like this: "The tale of y-tales [or: y-tolds] less than 6 amounts to five."

Comment: @HansAdler Prefixes or adjuncts. I think adjuncts especially would be suitable for potentially creating words for concepts like the integer, and even modular numbers. It's probably just a matter of actually comming up with it. After all, we did the same thing with Greek/Latin for medicine and the sciences; I see little reason it could not be done in another language. Maybe something like "wholetale" for integer and "slicetale" for factions or radixed numbers. "Wraptale" might work for modular numbers, we already call it "wrap-around" arithmetic.

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing the Danish example. It is also worth mentioning that, as in Dutch (_taal_), the Danish word for ‘speak/talk’ is _tale_ (Icelandic _tala_), which also derives from _tal_. In fact _tælle_ ‘count’ is merely a causative of it. Icelandic _telja_ is clearer in that the umlauting causative suffix _-ja_ is still clearly visible. And of course German _(be)zahlen_ ‘pay’ is another derivative of the same basic concept.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Thanks, I hoped someone would do that if necessary.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, in your opinion, would you say "tale" would be more like "talk" while "tally" is more appropriate here?

Comment: @PatrickKelly The verb _tale_ in Danish means to speak, or to talk. The noun that means ‘number’ is _tal_ (plural also _tal_).

Comment: "Tale" was Poul Anderson's choice in his essay ["Uncleftish Beholdings"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncleftish_Beholding), e.g., "atomic number" = "uncleftish tale". The counting sense of "tell" survives in the expression "all told".

Answer (score 10):

Wiktionary says

> **[rīm](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rim#Old_English)**
>
> **Etymology**
>   Proto-Germanic *[rīmą](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Germanic/r%C4%ABm%C4%85) (“number, count, series”), from Proto-Indo-European *re(i)- (“to reason, count”). Akin to Old Frisian *rīm*, Old Saxon *-rīm*, Old High German rīm, Icelandic rím
>
> **Noun**
>   *rīm*
>   1. a number, counting, reckoning, numeral; calendar
>   *Rim miclade monna mægþe geond middan-geard* — Cædmon’s Metrical Paraphrase
>   sum; enumeration
>   2. sum; enumeration
>
> **Derived terms**
>
> - gerīm n. — A number, computation, measurement, calendar, diary
> - rīman — to count, number; tell, enumerate, relate; account, esteem as
> - rīmāþ m. — oath by a number of persons
> - rīmbōc — calendar
> - rīmcræft m. — arithmetic; calendar
> - rīmcræftig — skilled in reckoning
> - rīmcræftiga m. — one skilful at figures
> - rīmgetæl, rīmgetel n. — number
> - rīmre m. — reckoner, calculator
> - rīmtæl n. — number
> - rīmtalu f. number

The word [rhyme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyme#Etymology) is derived from the OE  *rīm*

> ... from Old French *rime* or *ryme*, which may be derived from Old Frankish *rīm, a Germanic term meaning "series, sequence" attested in Old English (**Old English rīm meaning "enumeration, series, numeral"**) and Old High German *rīm*, ultimately cognate to Old Irish *rím*, Greek ἀριθμός arithmos "number". Alternatively, the Old French words may derive from Latin *rhythmus*, from Greek ῥυθμός (rhythmos, rhythm).

Source: Wikipedia

From the [Anglo Saxon Dictionary](https://archive.org/stream/anglosaxondictio00tolluoft#page/424/mode/2up) (1921) the term *getæl* was used in Old English to mean *a number*.

[image][image]

and from the same source the entry for **rīm**

[image]

Comment: A while now reading quite a bit of Icelandic and I've never come across that word. If I can confirm the definition through other sources, this might fit very well.

Comment: Everything I've found has this at least comming from Latin, possibly even Greek. Even your source states this. I'm looking for something not of Italic origin, which would exclude Latin.

Comment: @PatrickKelly I believe it would be impossible to say with certainty if  [Proto-Germanic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic_language) borrowed a Latin term or vice-versa. But for hypotheses sake, let us imagine that they did, once a "loanword" has been borrowed and used extensively, it becomes an integral part of that language, its original meaning and identity is no longer  "foreign" to its speakers, for all intents and purposes it is fully assimilated.

Comment: I'm well aware of the difficulty. Prior to written records, it's basically anyones best guess. That's why this is just a curiosity. I'm taking a bit of a reductive approach: if it can be found to have come from a non-Germanic language, it definately does not fufil the criteria. If at the end, I have no answers, then we might not have had a native word for it. I'm also not at all interested in what's assimilated now. "floccinaucinihilipilification" is part of English now, but it's obviously not Germanic in origin.

Comment: On what evidence do you base your claim that *rīm* is "obviously" not Germanic in origin? [Frankish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankish_language) which is mentioned in the Wiki link is not French but West-Germanic. The Wikipedia link which I quoted says *The word [rhyme] is derived from Old French *rime* or *ryme*, which **may be derived from Old Frankish *rīm,***

Comment: Collins English Dictionary (2012) has it as "C16: from Latin rhythmus, from Greek rhuthmos ; related to rhein to flow"

Online Etymology Dictionary has it as "n.
1550s, "rhymed verse, metrical movement," from Latin rhythmus "movement in time," from Greek rhythmos "measured flow or movement, rhythm; proportion, symmetry; arrangement, order; form, shape, wise, manner; soul, disposition," related to rhein "to flow," from PIE root *sreu- "to flow" (see rheum )."

Even your own source states "Alternatively, the Old French words may derive from Latin rhythmus, from Greek ῥυθμός (rhythmos, rhythm)."

Comment: The key word is "may" and I guess you are looking at "rhyme", which Wikipedia also says "may" be derived from Frankish.

Comment: @PatrickKelly The Proto-Germanic word _*rīmą-_ and its descendants are quite positively not from Latin, because the sound change whereby the _-th-_ in the middle was lost didn’t happen until much later, in Old French. There are two different roots/developments: 1) PIE _*sreu̯-_ ‘flow’ > Gk. _ῥυθμός_ ‘rhyme/rhythm’ > Lat. _rhythmus_ > Old French _ri(t)me_. 2) PIE _*h₂rei̯H-_ ‘count, number’ > Gk. _ἀριθμός_ ‘number’, but also PG _*rīma-_ ‘number’, Old Irish _rím_ ‘number’, Welsh _rhif_ ‘number’. The two were quite distinct in most languages, except that Greek introduced the _θ_ from [cont’d→]

Comment: [→cont’d] one into the other (uncertain from which to which). But in Old French, they definitely had the inherited (from Latin) _ri(t)me_ ‘rhythm/rhyme’, and very likely also a Frankish loan word _rime_ ‘number, tally’, and if the _t_ in _ritme_ hadn’t been lost already, the closeness of those two words in both form and meaning definitely helped it along, so the words merged. From then on, Old French _rime_ meaning ‘rhyme/rhythm’ spread to English, German, Scandiwegian, etc. But it’s a different word from the original Germanic one, basically identical, but with a different meaning.