# What is non-borrowed English word meaning "calculate", "compute", "count"?

Tags: etymology, old-english

What is non-borrowed native English word meaning "calculate", "compute", "count"? What was the word for these things in Old English?

Comment: "native English" presumablty meaning autochthonous? Or at least one that existed before the Norman Conquest (*i.e.* before the English language)?

Comment: @TimLymington non-borrowed.

Comment: related: [Is there a Germanic word for the Latin “number”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250325/is-there-a-germanic-word-for-the-latin-number)

Comment: If  by "non-borrowed" you mean 'not derived from any other language'  then clearly there is no such thing. If you mean 'from a Germanic rather than Romance root' you should use less misleading language.

Comment: @TimLymington by non-borrowed I just mean "non-borrowed".

Comment: Nothing in English is "borrowed". We stole it all fair and square and will not be giving it back.

Comment: *Calculate*, *compute* and *count* are all perfectly ordinary English words. None of them are borrowed.

Comment: @Gilles they are borrowed from Latin.

Comment: No, they aren't. They *were* borrowed, maybe, a long time ago, but they've long gone native. They have perfectly cromulent English morphology, phonology, spelling, etc. They are no more and no less “borrowed from Latin” than a word like *reckon* is “borrowed from German”.

Comment: @Gilles so I was asking about words not borrowed any time ago. Reckon was not borrowed from German, according the Wikitionary.

Comment: @Anixx - So what you're basically looking for is a word that could show up in [Uncleftish Beholding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncleftish_Beholding)?

Comment: Old English has been dead and gone for almost a thousand years. It's fine to ask for a word in Old English, but you cannot say that English somehow “borrowed” words like *calculate*, *compute*, and *count* from Latin or French; it never did. The streams of Norse and Norman French flowed into what we now read and speak *sans* borrowings. Make no mistake: English does indeed borrow words from other tongues, but the ones you have named are not amongst these. Rather, look if you will to the likes of *naïve façade* for words truly lent and borrowed—but for one, the only such you’ll’ve read in this.

Comment: @tchrist If words from a different language (Norman French in this case) flowed into English _sans_ borrowings, how exactly would you say they did flow in? Appropriating a word from a different language into your own and beginning to use it as part of your own language is precisely what a borrowing is. _Count_ is as much a borrowing as _naïve_ and _façade_ are; they were just borrowed at different times.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm going with the thought that what we now call English is more of a creole than it is a soupçon. :) Mostly I was wanting to make an answer that only had words that had come to us from some Germanic background only instead of from some Roman tongue one way or the other, which is a fun thing to do now and then. It’s damned tight, though: good luck. :)

Comment: I prefer the term "Teutonic" to "Germanic", the latter being (confusingly) close to "German" and so can easily give a layperson the wrong idea. Edward Gibbon (Decline ... etc) used both as having basically the same meaning. Teutonic was the first language (of that language branch) that the Romans came in contact with and is preferable for that reason too.

Comment: Why are there 8 downvotes??? Because the OP uses the noun-phrase "non-borrowed native English word"? Is that it? Well, here's an eye-opener folks, the OP is not self-professed expert. So how about suggesting that he uses a different phrase, something like: `What is the earliest known term in the English language that means "calculate", "compute", "count"?` Would that make the *real* experts happier? Jeez...

Comment: I didn't upvote because there was no research and it didn't show any effort, but the DVs are prejudicial.

Comment: Wow, it's sad to see the linguistic ignorance in the comments above, on a site supposedly "for linguists." The distinction between borrowed and inherited vocabulary is a basic concept of historical linguistics. The etymological processes that give us "count," "calculate," "compute" and other loans are qualitatively different from the ones that give us "reckon" and other inherited words.

Comment: @Gilles: It's not correct in any sense to say "reckon" was “borrowed from German”. It was inherited from Common Germanic, which is quite different. Obviously if you pretend that we should be considering infinite/"back to Proto-Human" time scales you could say "well, any inherited word might have originally been a borrowing" but it is clear that a question like this is asking about what we have been able to reconstruct, not whether there are any words that we can say for 100% certain were never borrowings.

Comment: @kbro As many copyright reform activists would say: is it right to call it "stealing" if both languages get to keep that word?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni try copying and MP3 music file or a JPEG photo without the owner's permission and tell me that isn't copyright theft.  The owner still has the original, after all.  I'll concede on "stolen" in the language context, though, but "borrowed" is still wrong - taken, copied, mimicked, plagiarised are better.  I think the bottom line here is that the English didn't have much time to make up their own words because they were too busy fighting off invaders. Or assimilating them.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: without a proper definition of 'borrowed', the answer would be (and the answer to your proposed replacement is) 'calculate, compute, count'.  Doesn't seem unreasonable to downvote.

Comment: @TimLymington these 3 words are borrowed by any definition.

Comment: @TimLymington I'm not in the mindset to check the etymology of each and every word in your ‘answer’ but the OP is asking for a term that *means* the aforementioned words. .... just kidding 1560s for *calculate*, 1630s for *compute*, and  mid-14c for *count*. Now, that is my reply to your equally nitpicking risposte. and Anixx may I suggest that you show a little effort (in your question) and grace when native speakers are helping you understand that the aforementioned words are English. They're neither French nor Italian.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I am not interested in the oldest word. I know what the word for it was in Proto-Indo-European, it would be the oldest. I am just interested what were non-borrowed words used in this meaning in English.

Comment: @ Mari-Lou A the very you link refers borrowing words. Also, others: http://www.ruf.rice.edu/~kemmer/Words04/structure/borrowed.html ; https://msn.khnu.km.ua/pluginfile.php/202293/mod_resource/content/1/Lecture%205_Etymology.pdf ; http://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/EJ1082278.pdf Calque is a COMPLETELY DIFFERENT thing I am not asking about.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A this is the standard term, why should I link dictionaries to explain any word I use? This term is not worse than "loanword".

Comment: It's a pity you didn't expand your question and included a brief explanation as to why you used the term "borrowed" in order to silence your critics.   In light of the criticisms, and observations, in your position I would have clarified, and maybe adjusted my question. A bit more detail, explaining what you meant,  would have only improved the question's quality, and silenced the downvoters. I consider [loanword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword) and [calque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque) to be more appropriate terms, but you're right "borrowed" is also used by linguists.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A calque is a totally different thing.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A If a person does not understand "borrowing", he does not understand "loanword" as well. https://books.google.ru/books?id=i6bew0EnsswC&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=%22borrowed+vocabulary%22&source=bl&ots=xhL6BqnHH1&sig=4A9DVwk_e086c7VJ9JHv0J_Dq7g&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg76fszb_TAhVBYZoKHbWQDU4Q6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22borrowed%20vocabulary%22&f=false

Answer (score 37):

[Reckon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reckon) comes from the Old English *recenian,* meaning “to pay, arrange, dispose, reckon”.

Comment: How is this better than Josh's ''Tellan''? All those meanings aren't about calculation? ''Pay'' is to give something to someone else, ''arrange'' is like sorting, ''dispose''... No relation to counting... and ''reckon'' is for any kind of deduction?

Comment: @Malandy: To pay is to count out money. Definitely an etymological  relation.

Comment: Yes... But, that's 1/4 meanings, in contrast to "Tellan", where "count" is directly one of the meanings, while "tell", which can be connected to "teller", is the second one... Although, that has a bit of distance, as "telling" is any relating of information... But there's "telling the time"... And "Bank Tellers" were brought up...

Comment: While Malandy is going crazy with rage that _two_ answers are posted, it could be worth pointing out that this is the word used in Germany and the Scandinavian languages for all the words in the question: _calculate_, _compute_, _count_. Rechnen, räkna, regne, etc.

Comment: @Malandy: There are plenty of phrases in which "reckon" clearly has the meaning "count" or "calculate", e.g. "in the final reckoning", "ready reckoner", etc...

Answer (score 24):

***[Tellan](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/tellan#Old_English)*** was a an Old English term meaning:

> - to count
> - to tell

(Wiktionary)

***[Tellan](http://www.oldenglishtranslator.co.uk/):***

> - to tell reckon count number compute calculate account estimate consider think esteem believe charge against impute to assign state recount enumerate announce relate ~ gelíc compare.

(www.oldenglishtranslator.co.uk)

Comment: I'd always thought that the verb *tally* was related to this one, but it appears instead to have come down via Latin *talea* (like in Italian) via Medieval French, and not be cognate back in Proto-Germanic or Proto-Indoeuropean as far as I can tell.

Comment: @tchrist: on the other hand, *teller* is related, and for bank tellers, retains the original meaning of (approximately) "one who counts".

Comment: "Tell me how many of these things there are" Is all from Germanic... 'Think there's no word that came down to us with the meanings of "calculate" and "compute" as they are today, or human computers... A guess of the word if there were no [Latin-German mix](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_purism_in_English), like [this](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncleftish_Beholding)... (Thanks, [Bobson](http://www.english.stackexchange.com/questions/385852/what-is-non-borrowed-english-word-meaning-calculate-compute-count#comment909067_385852)...) A likely root is tellan, I suppose.

Answer (score 9):

The **Old English roots for "*number*" were both "rim" and "tæl"/"talu"** ([as can be seen by entering "number" and translating to Old English here](https://www.oldenglishtranslator.co.uk/)).

Using that as a starting point,

**tally**: (v) calculate the total number of;

**reckon**: (v) establish by counting or calculation; calculate.

To see that the etymology of tally goes back to the Old English, consider words zala/zahl.

Zahl in modern German means "a number".
[Zala](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zala#Old_High_German) meant "number" in the Old High German.

The fact that t/s sounds can be viewed as interchangeable and one can become permanently transitioned into the other can be seen from the Hebrew Tav/Sav.  Modern Hebrew dispensed with Sav altogether and uses Tav both where Tav and Sav used to be.

Officially, "tally" is considered to have entered English in the mid-English by the way of "cutting"->"entering notches"->"counting".  But the fact that its sound is so similar to "talu" seems too coincidental.

"reckon" came in as a variation on "rim".

Comment: No, English is not a mixture of German and French. English is a Germanic language, but it is not in any way German (at the stage when the ancestral forms of English and German were close enough to be the same language, there was no such thing as neither ‘English’ nor ‘German’), and being a Germanic language, it is certainly not French. Loan words are a complex matter, but words that make their way into one language through another is pretty much the most basic definition of what a borrowing is.

Comment: "[tally](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=tally)" is a loanword.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet, English didn't come to be from the modern German or modern French.  But it did form as a mix of German and French *as they existed at the time when English was formed*.  So words which came from either archaic German or archaic French are not loanwords.  They are part of the original English language.

Comment: @sumelic, tally is not a loanword.

Comment: @grovkin: Anixx's phrasing of the question (What was the word for these things in Old English?) implies that he is using a historical definition of "loanword" or "borrowing", not a contemporary one. All words from French are in fact considered to be loanwords in English from the perspective of historical linguistics. They can't be used as data points for the reconstruction of Proto-Germanic or Proto-Indo-European, the ancestors of English and Old English.

Comment: @sumelic, your argument is tautological.  You are trying to prove that English has 1 ancestor by saying that the reconstruction of this 1 ancestor from the 2nd ancestor of English is not possible.  My assertion is that English had two equally-contributing ancestors.  You are not disproving not disproving this assertion by your statements.

Comment: I hope you'll agree that the consensus of historical linguists is that "Old English" was a Germanic language. If you disagree, please explain. The question asks about a word for "calculate", "compute", "count" that existed in Old English. I don't think this answer satisfies that criterion.

Comment: @sumelic, read my answer again.  I said "Middle English".  Old English is not English.  At least no more than Germanic is German.

Comment: The actual question talks about Old English. Disagreeing with the underlying basis of the question doesn't make it unanswerable. I don't think it's helpful to provide an answer that goes against one of the explicit criteria of the original question. The question is not primarily about the definition of "borrowing" or the ancestry of Middle English. Anyway, I think we both understand each other's viewpoints as much as we ever will, and it doesn't look like we're going to come to an agreement.